# Calculation for scoring search results based or relevancy and age

Tags: math, lucene

I'm using Lucene to create a search engine, its all going well but I'm having to implement and algorithm for scoring results based on their relevancy and age. I have three inputs:

- Relevancy score - an example would be 2.68065834
- Age of document (in UNIX epoch format - e.g. number of seconds since 1970) - an example would be 1380979800
- Age scew (this is between 0 and 10 and is specified by the user and it allows them to control how much of an effect the age of a document has on the overall score)

What I'm doing currently is basically:

```
    ageOfDocumentInHours = age / 3600; //this is to avoid any overflows
    ageModifier = ageOfDocumentInHours * ageScew + 1; // scew of 0 results in relevancy * 1 
    overallScore = relevancy * ageModifier;
```

I know nothing about statistics - is there a better way to do this?

Thanks,

Joe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I ended up doing:

```
    public override float CustomScore(int doc, float subQueryScore, float valSrcScore)
    {
        float contentScore = subQueryScore;

        double start = 1262307661d; //2010

        if (_dateVsContentModifier == 0)
        {
            return base.CustomScore(doc, subQueryScore, valSrcScore);
        }

        long epoch = (long)(DateTime.Now - new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc)).TotalSeconds;
        long docSinceStartHours = (long)Math.Ceiling((valSrcScore - start) / 3600);
        long nowSinceStartHours = (long)Math.Ceiling((epoch - start) / 3600);

        float ratio = (float)docSinceStartHours / (float)nowSinceStartHours; // Get a fraction where a document that was created this hour has a value of 1
        float ageScore = (ratio * _dateVsContentModifier) + 1; // We add 1 because we dont want the bit where we square it bellow to make the value smaller

        float ageScoreAdjustedSoNewerIsBetter = 1;

        if (_newerContentModifier > 0)
        {
            // Here we square it, multiuply it and then get the square root. This serves to make newer content have an exponentially higher score than old content instead of it just being linear
            ageScoreAdjustedSoNewerIsBetter =  (float)Math.Sqrt((ageScore * ageScore) * _newerContentModifier);
        }

        return ageScoreAdjustedSoNewerIsBetter * contentScore;
    }
```

The basic idea is that the age score is a fraction where 0 is the first day of 2010 and 1 is right now. This decimal value is then multiplied by _dateVsContentModifier which optionally gives the date a boost over the relevancy score.

The age scroe is the squared, multiplied by _newerContentModifier and then square rooted. This causes newer content have a higher score than older content.

Joe